# JSDoc non-null assertion

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

In javascript, using JSDoc, I'm querying for an element on the page:

```js
// @ts-check

/** @type {HTMLInputElement} */
const element = document.getElementById('checkbox');
```

But I get the warning:

> Type 'HTMLElement | null' is not assignable to type 'HTMLInputElement'.
> Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'HTMLInputElement'.ts(2322)

Is there a way to assert this type as not null, like you would do in typescript with the `!` operator?

Comment: Facing the same problem, usually I add `@ts-ignore` after `/** @type {...} */` doc block. Looking for a better solution too.

Comment: I may be reproducing the error incorrectly... I took your code, added it to myself and shows me the type of the HTMLInputElement variable and does not swear at the mismatch of types

Answer (score 8):

After looking at the documentation, this can be accomplished using inline [casting](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html#casts). So in your case, the correct code should be like this:

```js
// @ts-check

const element = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */ (document.getElementById('checkbox'));
```

Also, make sure that after the `/** @type {...} */` annotation you need to wrap your code using parentheses.

Comment: If it still complains you can cast to `unknown` first: `/** @type {HTMLInputElement} */ (/** @type {unknown} */ (document.getElementById('checkbox')));`